# Replace Regex Variable

Tags: java, html, regex, replaceall

Hi I’m trying to use a replaceAll in java, to delete some html content of image:

This is my input

```
String html = '&nbsp;asd<i>&nbsp;qwe qwe<u>qweqwe</u></i><u>wqeqwesd.<img alt="vechile" src="urldirectionstring" style="float:left; height:190px; width:400px" /></u>';
```

So what I’m trying to do is replace all content of `<img ...>` and just return in replace this:

```
"Image Url: urldirectionstring";
```

So just replace the tag img, all the rest, let it, only touch this tag, and for now I have this, but its not enougth;

```
String replaceImg = html.replaceAll("<img[^>]*/>","Image Url: "+$srcImgdirection);
```

So, as you can see, I don’t have an idea how to get the urldirectionstring as variable in the replace.

----------- LAST EDIT -----------

I found this regex to get the urlstringdirection, but now I don’t how to replace it only and add the text:

```
String replaceImg = html.replaceAll("<img.*src="(.*)"[^>]*/?>","Image Url: "+$srcImgdirection);
```

Comment: are you aware that there are libraries for parsing HTML properly, and regex are not very suited to the task?

Comment: I agree with Patrick but for future application of `replaceAll()`: you can access the capturing groups in the replacement string via `$group_number`, .e.g `replaceAll("src=\"([^\"]*)\"","src=\"prefix$1suffix\"")` to surround the attribute content with `"prefix"` and `"suffix".

Comment: However, as Patrick already pointed out regular expressions are no good fit for irregular languages such as hmtl (e.g. what happens with nested tags?) unless you _really_ know _everything_ that is to be expected. As an example, your expression `<img.*src...` would match multiple image tags and everything in between at once. To fix that you could make the quantifier reluctant (i.e. `.*?`) to match as little as possible but the next question would be: what if there are image tags without `src` attribute or where the value is surrounded by single quotes instead of double quotes? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: im using a library that generate the element image so are always with teh same style @Thomas tahnks!

Comment: And if you should ever upgrade to a newer version of that library, are you certain it will continue to generate HTML that can be parsed that way?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
String replaceImg = html.replaceAll(".*<img.*src=\"(.*?)\".*", "Image Url: $1");
```

This replaces the entire string and the output would be only `Image Url: urldirectionstring` (note that `$1` contains the string matched in the expression, but just the part inside the parenthesis - basically each pair of parenthesis create "groups" that can be referenced later; as the regex contains only one pair, that's the first group, so you can reference it with `$1`)

If you want to replace only the img tag and keep the other tags intact, you could use:

```
String replaceImg = html.replaceAll("<img.*src=\"(.*?)\"[^>]*/?>", "Image Url: $1");
```

In this case, the output will be:
`&nbsp;asd<i>&nbsp;qwe qwe<u>qweqwe</u></i><u>wqeqwesd.Image Url: urldirectionstring</u>`